# barrier with dynamic number of parties in java

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, barrier

I want a barrier with a dynamic number of parties in java. I came across [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html), but this solution is for java 7 which I unfortunately cannot use.

Is there some solution for java 6. How should I satisfy the need for having a barrier with a variable number of waiters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to use a Phaser. There is a backport for Phaser that you can use in Java 6.
Download it from [JSR 166y backport](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/jsr166y.jar)

Comment: I have written an implementation which seems to work fine for my case. In case there is some problem I will go with the backport you mentioned. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's hard to write! And even harder to maintain. Sometimes it pays to be safe!

Answer (score 0):

What about CyclicBarrier?

like said in Phaser:

> similar in functionality to CyclicBarrier and CountDownLatch but supporting more flexible usage.

is there some functionality you need that missing in those classes?

Edit: 
After some googling I don't see something like this,
Don't know how complicated your problem, and how you should synchronized all your members in the barrier, but you can implement some simple parties sync with hierarchy of  CyclicBarrier

Comment: No, the question indicates having variable number of parties on the barrier, which CyclicBarrier doesn't support and Phaser does.

Comment: Oh, for some reason I thought CyclicBarrier have this, sorry. see my edit.